# Robocopy - Only copy if path is valid and directory is absent

Tags: robocopy

I have a robocopy process, but I don't want it to nuke other people's stuff if an input is botched. The process copies a directory from a source to a remote destination, but I only want it to do so if the remote destination isn't there. How can I set that up?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check if a directory is already present with a little help from PowerShell's [Test-Path cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-5.1):

```cs
param(
    [string]$InputPath,
    [string]$OutputPath,
    [string]$rc_parameter
)

if((Test-Path -Path $OutputPath -PathType Container) -eq $true){
    Write-Out "Output-Path already exists - aborting!"
    Exit
}else{
    Start-Process robocopy -ArgumentList "`"$InputPath`" `"$OutputPath`" $rc_parameter" -NoNewWindow -Wait
    Write-Out "If Robocopy did not throw any errors, everything went fine!"
}
```

Just save it as `myrobocopyscript.ps1`, then start a PowerShell-console and type:

```cs
# Syntax:
.\myrobocopyscript.ps1 -InputPath "<YOUR_INPUT-PATH>" -OutputPath "<YOUR_OUTPUT-PATH>" -rc_parameter "/<YOUR_PARAMETERS>"

# Example:
.\myrobocopyscript.ps1 -InputPath "D:\Downloads" -OutputPath "E:\NewFolder" -rc_parameter "/MIR /R:5 /W:15"`)
```

You can of course also use `Test-Path` for your `$InputPath`: just add another `if(Test-Path)`-condition for that.

---

Another (fully manual) option is to divide your existing operation into three steps:

1. Use [Robocopy's `/L`-Switch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx). This will just list all operations that Robocopy would do - without actually doing them. (You could write a `/LOG:`-File, so you can use a text editor to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in step 2)
2. Check the output for `EXTRA` files and if none are shown,
3. You can run Robocopy without `/L`.

However, I don't think that this will be very useful, as it is easy to miss information when more than a few dozen files should be processed.